# Python memory leak in big data structes (lists, dicts) -- what could be the reason?

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, python-3.x

The code is *extremely simple*. It shouldn't have any leaks since all is done *inside the function*. And *nothing is returned*.
I have a function which goes over all lines in a file (~20 MiB) and puts them all into a list.
Mentioned function:

```
def read_art_file(filename, path_to_dir):
    import codecs
    corpus = []
    corpus_file = codecs.open(path_to_dir + filename, 'r', 'iso-8859-15')
    newline = corpus_file.readline().strip()
    while newline != '':
        # we put into @article a @newline of file and some other info
        # (i left those lists blank for readability)
        article = [newline, [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
        corpus.append(article)
        del newline
        del article
        newline = corpus_file.readline().strip()
    memory_usage('inside function')
    for article in corpus:
        for word in article:
            del word
        del article
    del corpus
    corpus_file.close()
    memory_usage('inside: after corp deleted')
    return
```

Here is the main code:

```
memory_usage('START')
path_to_dir = '/home/soshial/internship/training_data/parser_output/'
read_art_file('accounting.n.txt.wpr.art', path_to_dir)
memory_usage('outside func')
time.sleep(5)
memory_usage('END')
```

All `memory_usage` just prints amount of KiB allocated by the script.

#### Executing the script

If I run the script, it gives me:

> START memory: 6088 KiB
>   inside memory: 393752 KiB (20 MiB file + lists occupy 400 MiB)
>   inside: after corp deleted memory: 43360 KiB
>   outside func memory: **34300** KiB (34300-6088= **28 MiB leaked**)
>   FINISH memory: 34300 KiB

#### Executing without lists

And if I do *absolutely* the same thing, but with appending `article` to the `corpus` commented out:

```
article = [newline, [], [], [], [], [], ...]  # we still assign data to `article`
# corpus.append(article)  # we don't have this string during second execution
```

This way output gives me:

> START memory: **6076** KiB
>   inside memory: 6076 KiB
>   inside: after corp deleted memory: 6076 KiB
>   outside func memory: 6076 KiB
>   FINISH memory: **6076** KiB

### QUESTION:

Hence, **this way all memory is being freed**. I need to have all memory freed since I'm going to process hundreds of such files.
Is it that I do something wrong or it is the CPython interpreter bug?

**UPD**. This is how I check memory consumption (taken from some other stackoverflow question):

```
def memory_usage(text = ''):
    """Memory usage of the current process in kilobytes."""
    status = None
    result = {'peak': 0, 'rss': 0}
    try:
        # This will only work on systems with a /proc file system
        # (like Linux).
        status = open('/proc/self/status')
        for line in status:
            parts = line.split()
            key = parts[0][2:-1].lower()
            if key in result:
                result[key] = int(parts[1])
    finally:
        if status is not None:
            status.close()
    print('>', text, 'memory:', result['rss'], 'KiB  ')
    return
```

Comment: you're not actually deleting the corpus list in your code? also you never explicitly close the corpus_file

Comment: how are you measuring the memory consumption?

Comment: @CameronSparr, thank you. I updated the code and debugging output results.

Comment: @mgilson, I added my memory testing function as you asked. thank you

Comment: If you invoke `read_art_file` twice, what is the reported memory usage?  Is it growing (a leak) or staying the same (per mgilson's answer/hypothesis below)?

Comment: This is not a memory leak. It is an artifact of how you are measuring memory usage. You are seeing the amount of memory that the Python process holds from the operating system; Python may reuse that memory for different objects over the life of the process in lieu of requesting more memory from the OS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please note that python **never guarantees** that any memory that your code uses will actually get returned to the OS.  All that garbage collection guarantees is that the memory used by an object which has been collected is free to be used by another object at some future time.

From what I've read<sup>1</sup> about the Cpython implementation of the memory allocator, memory gets allocated in "pools" for efficiency.  When a pool is full, python will allocate a new pool.  If a pool contains only dead objects, Cpython actually free the memory associated with that pool, but otherwise it doesn't.  This can lead to multiple partially full pools hanging around after a function or whatever.  However, this doesn't really mean it is a "memory leak".  (Cpython still knows about the memory and could potentially free it at some later time).

<sup><sup>1</sup>I'm not a python dev, so these details are likely to be incorrect or at least incomplete</sup>

Comment: Also note that memory which isn't actively used can be flushed to cache, so even if Python isn't giving it back to the OS it can still be reused.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- Yes, that's what I meant by "is free to be used by another object at some future time".  If you know more about the details here, feel free to edit/correct any statements above that I may have gotten incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant that the memory could be used by another program entirely without having to return it to the OS first.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- Oh ... Interesting.  I have no knowledge of this.  Neat.

Answer (score 1):

This loop

```
for article in corpus:
    for word in article:
        del word
    del article
```

does not free memory. `del word` simply decrements the reference count of the object referenced by the name `word`. However, your loop *increments* the reference count of each object by one when the loop variable is set. In other words, there is no net change in the reference count of any object due to this loop.

When you comment out the call to `corpus.append`, you are not keeping any references to objects read from the file from one iteration to the next, so the interpreter is free to deallocate the memory earlier, which accounts for the decrease in memory you observe.

Comment: But I still do have `del corpus` line. Did you see it?

Comment: Yes. And that decrements the reference count to the list referenced by `corpus` by one. If the reference count to that list reaches 0, and there are no other references to anything contained in that list, *then* those items may all be garbage-collected. But if you comment out the call to `corpus.append`, that list starts life as--and remains--an empty list, with nothing to garbage-collect.

Comment: Yes, but my question is: if i do `del` the list in both executions, the resultive amount of memory should be the same after exiting the function isn't it?

Comment: No. Commenting out `corpus.append` reduces the amount of memory your program allocates, since the memory that `article` references is reused while you are reading the file, since nothing is saved in `corpus` over the course of the loop.